# dropdown menu link to specifict section in a page

Tags: menu, dropdown

I have index.html and the catalog.html, in this page I have some Id in order to move throw diferents sections in that page.

I have a menu, with Hone and Catalog, this option it´s a dropdownmenu, so, what I need is if I´m index and clic on catalog can go to specific section (named "canal-prisma") of cataglo page, I have this code but didn´t work, thank you for your help

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="catalogo.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cat&aacute;logo<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">                
            <li><a href="catalogo.html#canal-prisma">CANAL PRISMA</a></li>

          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to go to a section on the page with the *id* or *name* attribute set as canal-prisma? If you set the id attribute, you should change that to the  "name" attribute. Otherwise, more code is really needed to determine the answer to your question.

For example, in order to create a section of the page called canal-prisma:

```
<a href="catalog.html#canal-prisma">Go to the Canal Prisma section</a>
```

And in catalog.html:

```
<a name="canal-prisma">#</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have in the index.html menu
 <li><a href="catalogo.html#canal-prisma">CANAL PRISMA</a></li>

and in Catalog.html

`code`<a name="canal-prisma" id="canal-prisma" style="padding-top:60px;">CANAL PRISMA</a>`code`

But doesn´t work.....

Comment: Could you include a link to a JSFiddle or the website this is located at? It would be best if I could work off of that.

Comment: Wait, in the comment, you say the file is called catalog.html, but in the code, you call it catalogo.html... could that be the issue?

Comment: No no... sorry, I had a problem with jquery, I fixed it , It worked excelent, btw you know how can i move between sections in smooth way?